# The data is failing to be inserted into the SQL database using Entity Framework Core with a Blazor app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor

I am working on an app that allows users to review data they have entered into a form. When the submit button is clicked, this data should be inserted into the database. However, I encounter the following error when the submit button is clicked:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\Apps\CPS Surplus\CPS Surplus\
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0 initialized 'WASPOContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.0' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (134ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [b].[BuildingID], [b].[BuildingLink], [b].[BuildingName], [b].[BuildingSubFlag], [b].[DESENo], [b].[LocCode]
      FROM [dbo].[BuildingList] AS [b]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [b].[BuildingID], [b].[BuildingLink], [b].[BuildingName], [b].[BuildingSubFlag], [b].[DESENo], [b].[LocCode]
      FROM [dbo].[BuildingList] AS [b]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [b].[BuildingID], [b].[BuildingLink], [b].[BuildingName], [b].[BuildingSubFlag], [b].[DESENo], [b].[LocCode]
      FROM [dbo].[BuildingList] AS [b]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (45ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [b].[BuildingID], [b].[BuildingLink], [b].[BuildingName], [b].[BuildingSubFlag], [b].[DESENo], [b].[LocCode]
      FROM [dbo].[BuildingList] AS [b]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [b].[BuildingID], [b].[BuildingLink], [b].[BuildingName], [b].[BuildingSubFlag], [b].[DESENo], [b].[LocCode]
      FROM [dbo].[BuildingList] AS [b]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [r].[CodeID], [r].[ReasonDescription]
      FROM [dbo].[Reasons] AS [r]
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (49ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 450), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (DbType = Int32), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [dbo].[SurplusItemsNew] ([ID], [CPSNumber], [Description], [ReasonCodeID], [RetirementStatus], [SurplusStatus])
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5);
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Surplus.Data.WASPOContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
      The statement has been terminated.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      ClientConnectionId:52edd412-7090-43ef-9b02-f7cb7cf5069e
      Error Number:8152,State:30,Class:16
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.
      The statement has been terminated.
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__188_0(Task`1 result)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      ClientConnectionId:52edd412-7090-43ef-9b02-f7cb7cf5069e
      Error Number:8152,State:30,Class:16
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Here is the form page markup and code:

```
@page "/summary"
@attribute [Authorize]
@using System.Text.Json;
@inject IJSRuntime _js
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using Blazored.LocalStorage
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal
@using Surplus.Data
@using Surplus.Models.WASPO
@inject CSPNumerManager CspNumberService

<PageTitle>Summary</PageTitle>

<RadzenGrid  Data="@filteredSessionData" TItem="FormData">

    <Columns>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="BuildingName" Title="School" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="CPSNumber" Title="CPS Number"  />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="Description" Title="Item Description" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="ReasonDescription" Title="Reason For Surplus" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="Edit">
            <Template Context="data">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <RadzenButton Icon="edit" Style="background-color: #005570;" Click="() => EditItem(data)"></RadzenButton>
                </div>
            </Template>
        </RadzenGridColumn>
    </Columns>
</RadzenGrid>
<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570"
              Text="Submit"
              Click = "YourSaveFunction">
</RadzenButton>


    <div class="back-button">
    <RadzenButton Icon="print" Style="background-color: #005570; float: left; vertical-align: text-top; text-align: center" Click="PrintMe"></RadzenButton>
</div>
@inject Data.WASPOContext dbContext
@code {

    private FormData formData = new FormData(); // Create an instance of FormData
    private async Task PrintMe()
        => await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("window.print");

    // Define the FormData class if it's not already defined
    public class FormData
    {
        public string BuildingName { get; set; }
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
        public int SurplusStatus { get; set; }
    }

    // Read the stored local storage data
    private List<FormData> sessionData = new List<FormData>();

    // Filtered session data without null CPSNumber
    private List<FormData> filteredSessionData = new List<FormData>();

    // Inject the ILocalStorageService
    [Inject]
    private ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    protected SecurityService Security { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Load the data from local storage
        try
        {
            sessionData = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");

            // Filter out rows with null CPSNumber
            filteredSessionData = sessionData.Where(row => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.CPSNumber)).ToList();

            // Set the same BuildingName for all rows
            if (filteredSessionData.Count > 0)
            {
                var buildingName = filteredSessionData[0].BuildingName;
                filteredSessionData.ForEach(row => row.BuildingName = buildingName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private void EditItem(FormData data)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Form"); // Replace with the actual Razor page URL
    }

    // public FormData sumbitForm = new FormData();

    private async Task YourSaveFunction()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in filteredSessionData)
            {
                var newItem = new SurplusItemsNew
                    {
                        ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), // Ensure unique ID
                        CPSNumber = item.CPSNumber,
                        Description = item.Description,
                        SurplusStatus = 1,
                    };

                dbContext.SurplusItemsNews.Add(newItem);
            }
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            NotificationService.Notify(NotificationSeverity.Success, "Data Saved", "The data has been successfully saved to the database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NotificationService.Notify(NotificationSeverity.Error, "Save Failed", $"An error occurred while saving the data: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

<style>
    .back-button {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
    }

    .back-button a {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #005570;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .back-icon {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the service code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Surplus.Models.WASPO
{
    [Table("SurplusItemsNew", Schema = "dbo")]
    public partial class SurplusItemsNew
    {
        public SurplusItemsNew()
        {
            // Automatically generate a new GUID
            ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); 
        }

        [Key]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int? ReasonCodeID { get; set; }
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public int? SurplusStatus { get; set; }
        public int? RetirementStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my `DbContext`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Surplus.Models.WASPO;

namespace Surplus.Data
{
    public partial class WASPOContext : DbContext
    {
        public WASPOContext()
        {
        }

        public WASPOContext(DbContextOptions<WASPOContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        partial void OnModelBuilding(ModelBuilder builder);

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList>().HasNoKey();
            builder.Entity<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason>().HasNoKey();

            // builder.Entity<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew>().HasNoKey();

            builder.Entity<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList>()
              .Property(p => p.BuildingID)
              .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
              .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);

            builder.Entity<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason>()
              .Property(p => p.CodeID)
              .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
              .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
            this.OnModelBuilding(builder);
        }

        public DbSet<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList> BuildingLists { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason> Reasons { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew> SurplusItemsNews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: here is my DBO Object Code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Surplus.Models.WASPO
{
    [Table("SurplusItemsNew", Schema = "dbo")]
    public partial class SurplusItemsNew
    {

        public SurplusItemsNew()
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Automatically generate a new GUID
        }

        [Key]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public int? ReasonCodeID { get; set; }

        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }

        public int? SurplusStatus { get; set; }

        public int? RetirementStatus { get; set; }

    }
}
```

EDIT: here is the database table information:
[image]

Any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance

Comment: "String or binary data would be truncated" suggests you have a mismatch between your C# model types and your database types.   Without a view of your Dbo object, that's hard to predict.  You need to go review these.

Comment: Adding some more ideas to @MrCakaShaunCurtis good advice: You should annotate your  viewmodel `FormData` with`MaxLength` attribute (check this [MS form blazor sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/input-components?view=aspnetcore-8.0#multiple-option-selection-with-the-inputselect-component) and ensure do you have a data annotation validator on your forms.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have added the DBO Object code to the question. please see the edit in the question, also please let me know if you need anything else and thank you and dani for your help so far!!!

Comment: Without seeing the actual data types used in the database I can't provide an answer.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis thank you for the quick response I have added the datatypes from the databae in the question please check it out when you have a minute and thank you for all the help so far!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you define ID like this:

```cs
[Key] public string ID { get; set; }
```

And generate it like this:

```cs
ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Automatically generate a new GUID
```

which will look like this:

```
3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301
```

Count the number of letters.

In your dbo table object you define `ID` as `varchar(20)`.

Spot the problem?  36 letters won't fit into a 20 letter field.

The db type should probably be `uniqueidentifier`, and `not null`.

Comment: That was the issue!!!! you are a legend thank you so much for all you help!!!!!!!!!